# Display distinct rows of a table with the sum of a column of all duplicate rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, distinct-values

There are two tables :

`Tasks` table :

```
    TaskName (PK)
```

`TaskAllocation` table :

```
     AllocationID(PK),
     TaskName(F.K to TaskName in 'Tasks' Table),
     UserID( F.K to ID in 'Users' Table),
     EngineerType( F.K to ID in 'EngineerType' Table),         
     Start Date,
     End Date, 
     Hours,
     Location
```

'Users' Table :

```
     ID,
     FirstName,
     LastName
```

'EngineerTypes' Table :

```
     ID,
     Type
```

Each task can have multiple allocations.Hence, the taskname can occur multiple times in the Task Allocation table. The same task can be mapped to multiple users (UserID)

I need to display the selected task (given as input from U.I), the UserIDs allocated to that task, first occurrence of start date, first occurrence of end date and Sum(Hours) for each user of the selected tasks.

Example: `TaskAllocation` data :

```
     TaskName  UserID   TypeId StartDate EndDate Hours Location
      Task1    1          11    Feb 5     Feb 7   1     NULL
      Task1    1          11    Feb 6     Feb 7   2     NULL
      Task1    1          11    Feb 7     Feb 7   3     Onsite
      Task1    2          12    Feb 8     Feb 10  4     Offshore
      Task1    2          12    Feb 9     Feb 10  5     NULL
      Task1    2          12    Feb 10    Feb 10  6     NULL

     'EngineerTypes' data :
      ID   Type
      11   Type1
      12   Type2

     'Users' Data :
      ID     FirstName 
      1      Name1
      2      Name2
```

The query which I implemented was :

```
                                                                                              Select TaskAllocation.UserId as UserId,Users.FirstName as Name,
                                                                    TaskAllocation.EngineerType as TypeId,EngineerTypes.Type as Type,
                                                       min(TaskAllocation.StartDate) as AllocationStartDate,
                                                                       max(TaskAllocation.EndDate) as AllocationEndDate,
                                                         sum(TaskAllocation.Hours) as Hours, TaskAllocation.Location
                                                                            from TaskAllocation join Users on TaskAllocation.UserId=Users.ID 
                                                                          join EngineerTypes on EngineerTypes.ID = TaskAllocation.EngineerType
                                                                         where TaskAllocation.TaskName = Task1' group by                               
     FirstName,UserId,EngineerType,Type,AllocationStartDate,AllocationEndDate,Hours,                                                                                      
                                                                                    Location,TaskName order by TaskName, UserId
```

Output:                                                                                           UserId    Name TypeId Type AllocationStartDate AllocationEndDate Hours Location

```
    1. 126   Name1  11   Type1  2015-11-23      2015-11-25         0.1  NULL
    2. 126   Name1  11   Type1  2015-11-24      2015-11-25         0.2  NULL
    3. 126   Name1  11   Type1  2015-11-25      2015-11-25         0.3  NULL
    4. 127   Name2  12   Type2  2015-11-23      2015-11-25         0.2  NULL
    5. 127   Name2  12   Type2  2015-11-24      2015-11-25         0.3  NULL
    6. 127   Name2  12   Type2  2015-11-25      2015-11-25         0.4  NULL
```

Comment: Example data,output should be like and output don't match

Comment: Yes, witohut using joins the example data output is displayed, But now, I need some extra data also to be displayed along with it. So I used joins. After using joins the output is differing. Will include the other tables also in the question now.

Comment: ok ,please try to format the question removing unnessary things

Comment: try removing allocation startdate,endate,hours in your group by

Comment: Yes. Removed them and it worked.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below ways

**Method1:**

```
select taskname,
userid,
min(startdate) as'first occurence',
max(enddate) as'last occurence'
,sum(hours)
 from t1
 group by taskname,userid
```

**Method2:Cross apply**

```
 select 
 distinct taskname,userid,b.*
 from t1
 cross apply
 (select min(startdate) as Firstoccur,max(startdate) as secondocc,sum(hours) as hrs
 from t1 t2 where t1.taskname =t2.taskname and t1.userid=t2.userid
 group by t2.taskname,t2.userid) b
```

Method 3:
Window functions

```
 with cte
 as
 (
 select taskname,userid,
 min(startdate) over (partition by taskname,userid) as 'first',
 max(enddate) over (partition by taskname,userid) as 'second',
 sum(hours) over (partition by taskname,userid) as 'hrs',
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by taskname,userid order by taskname,userid) as rn
   from t1
   )
   select *from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the first method by including joins but it is displaying the duplicate rows.

Comment: Can you paste output

Comment: When you group by taskname ,userid and apply aggregations as per your sample data.you are not bound to get duplicates

Comment: Please see the question for the implemented query.